# Php form to add content to column without overwriting

Tags: php, postgresql

I need a form to add data to a column without overwriting the old data, I've tried variations on this which haven't worked. Ideally I want it with 3 hyphens as a spacer between the old and new, so if someone entered XXX, and there was already YYY then it would be saved as YYY---XXX, then if someone entered XXX and it was null, then updated with no hyphens, but I haven't solved the adding text bit yet.

Statement

```
<?php

$v = array();
$v[0] = $_POST['note'];
$v[1] = $_POST['product_id'];

$dbh = dbh_get();

$sql = 'UPDATE card SET notes = $v[0] + notes WHERE product=$v[1]';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($v);

dbh_free($dbh) ?>`
```

Comment: Never put user content directly into a database query!

Comment: @eisbehr why not? only two of us ever going to use it, it's not like it's publicly accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [string concatenation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)  operator in SQL is `||`. The `+` is to add numbers:

```
update card
   set notes = $v[0] || notes
where ...
```

Note that `a || b` yields `null` if any of the expressions is null. If `notes` can possibly be null in the table, use the null-safe `concat()` function:

```
update card
   set notes = concat($v[0], notes)
where ...
```

To add the "spacer" you can use `concat_ws()` which will automatically handle nulls or empty strings:

```
update card
   set notes = concat_ws('---', $v[0], notes)
where ...
```

Comment: doesn't update for me, but looks like it should, I'm reading some tutorials to see where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1):

As `@a_horse_with_no_name` already told you, you need to use a string concatenation operator, or as I would prefer, using `concat_ws`, as `+` is for numeric operations.

But there are two more *issues* in your example. First of all, you use a variable for putting a string into a sql query. That will work in general, but you need to put the variables into quotes `'`, in order to get a valid sql string. Like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE card SET notes = concat_ws('---', '{$v[0]}', notes) WHERE product = '{$v[1]}'";
```

This will let you create a correctly formatted sql statement. But it is still bad, because as I mentioned in the comments, you should never directly place user entered content into a database query. Even if it's only used for internal purpose. It would not be the first case where an unfriendly employee would like to harm internal data.

But even if it's not intended, this could break your script. If the value of `$v[0]` or `$v[1]` contains a single quote `'`, the sql query will become invalid. So please escape your values before placing them into the query. For `postgres` you can use `pg_escape_string` in php. Or maybe your class has an own function for this. But here is what it looks like:

```
$note = pg_escape_string($_POST['note']);
$product = pg_escape_string($_POST['product_id']);
$sql = "UPDATE card SET notes = concat_ws('---', '{$note}', notes) WHERE product = '{$product}'";
```

Comment: nice, this is what is working right now, I've added you escape string as well $query = "UPDATE card SET notes = CONCAT_WS('---','" . $v[0] . "', notes) WHERE reference='" . $v[1] . "'" took me ages playing with quotes to get it working, what is the difference with the {} you're using?

Comment: If you put strings into double quotes `"` you need to escape php variables inside it with `{}`. This is not always necessary when you use single quotes `'`. As sql query mostly uses single quotes for these values, I switched your example string to double quotes. But as you escaped them with `'" . $var . "'` you have no problem too, it's fine. @Kilisi